# Approximation with imperfect dichotomy oracle

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, approximation, binary-search

Given an unknown $x$ and an oracle $O(r)$ such that:

1. If $O(r)$ is true then $x \geq r$.
2. If $O(r)$ is false then $x < 2r$.

Conversely, the oracle has a defined behaviour only outside the interval $(x/2, x]$, and may output anything between.

We want to find a factor 2 approximation of $x$.

What is the strategy with a minimal number of calls to $O$?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried any strategy at all?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *best strategy*? The number of calls in generally depends on $x$, so it's not clear what a best strategy is.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus For the moment I have a very fast algorithm to find a factor 4 approximation : If we know a value r s.t. O(r/2) = True and O(r) = False, then we know that y in in [r/2, 2*r[.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  And for any starting point y, while O(y) = True we multiply y by 2 until we have O(y) = False, and conversely for O(y)=False to find such a value.
By the properties of the oracle, this terminates. We have a logarithmic complexity.
But when evaluating O(y * 2**k) for an integer k, we know that there is an index that separates the True values from the False.
Thus we can applicate binary search on this logarithmic scale to have a log(log(answer)) number of evaluations of the oracle.

Comment: @D.W. That's the point, it can give True or False and we don't know… I think you did not read well, the behaviour is defined only OUTSIDE this interval.

Comment: Take your strategy and change $2$ to $\sqrt{2}$ everywhere. Does this work?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No… Let's note $\$ = \sqrt(2)$, $\$\$ = 2$ etc… Given the same r such that $O(r/\$\$) = T$ and $O(r) = F$, we can have $O(r/\$\$\$) = T$, $O(r*\$) = F$ and any value of $O(r/\$)$ in either case $x \in [r/\$\$, r[$ and $x \in [r, r*\$\$[$

Comment: My proof is incomplete, because we could give other intervals than [r/2, r[ and [r, 2*r[, working on it :)

Comment: If the current suggestion works, why would a new idea be needed?

Comment: We have only a $\$\$\$ = 2*\sqrt(2)$ approximation.

Comment: Goodness.  That's an awful lot of comments.  Can you please edit the question to incorporate all relevant information in the question, and then delete or flag as obsolete all remaining comments?  Comments exist to help you improve the question.  Please don't use comments as an ongoing chat thread or for stream of consciousness musings and thoughts.  Instead, take some time to think about things on your own, then edit the question to show us what you tried, where you got stuck, and make sure to incorporate all relevant information into the question/answer so it is self-contained.

Comment: @D.W. I deleted most of the comments about the $2\sqrt2$ approximation and integrated them in my 4th paragraph :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found thanks to @YuvalFilmus 's advice! (if you want me to remove this answer and post it yourself, feel free to ask)

#### 1. We find a factor 4 approximation

If we know a value r s.t. O(r/2) = True and O(r) = False, then we know that x is in [r/2, 2*r[.

And for any starting point y, while O(y) = True we multiply y by 2 until we have O(y) = False, and conversely for O(y) = False to find such a value.

By the properties of the oracle, this terminates. We have a logarithmic complexity. But when evaluating $O(y \times 2^k)$ for an integer k, we know that there is an index that separates the True values from the False. Thus we can apply binary search on this logarithmic scale to have a $\log(\log(x))$ number of evaluations of the oracle.

#### 2. We transform a $2^{1+\frac{1}{k}}$ approximation in a $2^{1+\frac{1}{2k}}$ approximation

Suppose you know $x\in[a, b[$ with $\frac{b}{a} = 2^{1+\frac{1}{k}}$.

Take $c = a * 2^\frac{1}{2k}$.

We know that if $x \in [a, c[$, then $O(c)$ is false, and that if $x \in [2c, b[$, then $O(c)$ is true.

Thus we can eliminate one interval of ratio $2^\frac{1}{2k}$, and the remaining interval is of ratio $2^{1+\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2k}}$ = $2^{1+\frac{1}{2k}}$.

#### 3. Complexity

We make $\log(\log(x))$ calls to the oracle in the first stage, and then $i$ to get a $2^{1+\frac{1}{2^i}}$ approximation factor.

For example, if you work with integers, the stop condition is $ x * (2^{1 + \frac{1}{2^i}} - 2) < 1 $. A Taylor expansion gives us $i > \log(x) + 1$ with the first term, so $i > \log(x) + 2$ should be fine.

#### 4. Other strategies

Like shown below, more evaluations per step could get us immediately better approximation factors than 2.

However, it requires too much evaluations, with no improvement in the worst case when the oracle is a threshold function.

Let $x_1, x_2 = \frac{r}{2}, x_3, x_4=b, x_5, x_6=2r$ be numbers in geometric progression of ratio $\sqrt2$ with $r$ found after the first stage.

We know $O(x_2) = T, O(x_4) = F, O(x_6) = F$, and we know $x \in [x_2, x_6[$. We split this interval in 4 and look at the values of $O(x_1), O(x_3), O(x_5)$. We note $?$ when a value can be True or False.

For $x\in[x_2,x_3[$, the possible values are $?, F, F$.

For $x\in[x_3,x_4[$, the possible values are $T, ?, F$.

For $x\in[x_4,x_5[$, the possible values are $T, ?, F$.

For $x\in[x_5,x_6[$, the possible values are $T, T, ?$.

If we get $O(x_1) = F$ or $O(x_5) = T$, we know a $\sqrt2$ factor approximation of x. Else, the value of $x_3 = c$ allows us to eliminate either the leftmost or the rightmost interval, which is exactly the first step of the second stage of our general strategy to transform a $4 = 2^{1 + \frac{1}{1}}$ approximation into a $2\sqrt2 = 2^{1 + \frac{1}{2}}$ approximation.